# no visible @interface for Book declares the selector

Tags: objective-c

doesn't understand why, everything looks fine ;( but I got no visible @interface for Book declares the selector "initWithAuthor" in simplebookmanager.m I have also tried to shut down the Xcode and run again but didn't work

book.h

```
#import<Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Book : NSObject

@property NSString *author;
@property NSString *titel;
@property NSInteger price;
@property NSString *isbn;
@property NSString *course;

-  (id)initWithAuthor:(NSString *)aAuthor
                titel:(NSString*)aTitel
                price:(NSInteger)aPrice
                 isbn:(NSString*)anIsbn
               course:(NSString*)aCourse;
```

### @end

```
book.m

#import "Book.h"

@implementation Book 

    -(id)initWithAuthor:(NSString *)aAuthor
                  titel:(NSString*)aTitel
                  price:(NSInteger)aPrice
                   isbn:(NSString*)anIsbn
                 course:(NSString*)aCourse {
            self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        _author = [aAuthor copy];
        _titel  = [aTitel copy]; // ???
        _price  = aPrice;
        _isbn   = [anIsbn copy];
        _course = [aCourse copy];
        }
    return self;
    }

@end
------------------------------------------------------------
#import "SimpleBookManager.h"
#import "BookManagerProtocol.h"
#import "Book.h"

@interface SimpleBookManager()

@property NSMutableArray *allBooks;


@end

SimpleBookManager.m

@implementation SimpleBookManager

-(id)init {

    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        _allBooks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
         Book *b1 = [[Book alloc]initWithAuthor :@"Ben"];  <---- got error in this part


    }
    return self;
}


@end
---------------------------------------------------------
SimpleBookManager.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "BookManagerProtocol.h"
#import "Book.h"

@interface SimpleBookManager : NSObject<BookManagerProtocol>


@end
```

Answer (score 1):

The method being called here:

```
Book *b1 = [[Book alloc]initWithAuthor :@"Ben"];
```

Is not the same as this method:

```
-  (id)initWithAuthor:(NSString *)aAuthor
                titel:(NSString*)aTitel
                price:(NSInteger)aPrice
                 isbn:(NSString*)anIsbn
               course:(NSString*)aCourse;
```

You need to provide all the parameters of the method to call the correct method and thus avoid the warning.

For example:

```
Book *b1 = [[Book alloc]initWithAuthor:@"Ben"
                                 titel:@"Ford Escort Haynes Manual"
                                 price:11
                                  isbn:@"AAXXEE22"
                                course:@"Yup"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your:

```
Book *b1 = [[Book alloc]initWithAuthor :@"Ben"];
```

should be:

```
Book *b1 = [[Book alloc]initWithAuthor:@"authorName" titel:@"title" price:123 isbn:@"123" course:@"course"];
```

Comment: Your answer is incorrect; you don't use commas to separate parameters in Objective-C other than for varargs.

Comment: @trojanfoe of course! Can't believe I wrote that. I code obj-c 8 hrs a day and I write something like that. Amazing. I learned a lesson, don't answer questions when doing something else at the same time. I stand corrected and I've edited my answer. Up voted your comment. Thanks man.

Comment: Not a problem, I know how it is - it's like when you forget to how to spell a word.  Upvoted your answer too then ;-)