# no visible interface for QMBParallaxScrollViewController declare the selector viewControllerDidScroll

Tags: ios, objective-c

this question had mentioned many time here the question is big and maybe i am not able to get whats is wrong in my code so for that purpose i asked my question what i am trying to do is to do mix between two library found on the internet the first one is [QMBParallaxScrollViewController](https://github.com/quemb/QMBParallaxScrollViewController) and the second one is [M6ParallaxController](https://github.com/peterpaulis/M6ParallaxController) to get a stunning view controller [image: view] everything is going to be fine just in one case in my bottomViewController which is in my case the scrollviewController i am calling a method that when the view is scrolling we need to call a method inside another class the scrollViewController class contain this :

```
#import "SampleScrollViewController.h"
#import "QMBParallaxScrollViewController.h"
#import "UIViewController+QMBParallaxScrollViewController.h"
   @interface SampleScrollViewController (){

}

@end

@implementation SampleScrollViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib{


}
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {



    QMBParallaxScrollViewController * parallaxController = [self parallaxScrollViewController];

    [parallaxController tableViewControllerDidScroll:self]; //here is the error 

}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)dealloc{

}


#pragma mark - QMBParallaxScrollViewHolder

- (UIScrollView *)scrollViewForParallaxController{

    return self.scrollView;
}

- (IBAction)closeButtonTouchUpInside:(id)sender{
    [self.parentViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    // close button
}

@end






and inside the QMBParallaxScrollViewController contain this:


//
//  QMBParallaxScrollViewController.m
//  QMBParallaxScrollView-Sample
//
//  Created by Toni Möckel on 02.11.13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Toni Möckel. All rights reserved.
//

#import "QMBParallaxScrollViewController.h"
#import "MapViewController.h"

@interface QMBParallaxScrollViewController (){
    BOOL _isAnimating;
    float _startTopHeight;
    float _lastOffsetY;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *backgroundView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *foregroundView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIScrollView *backgroundScrollView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIScrollView *foregroundScrollView;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITapGestureRecognizer *topViewGestureRecognizer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITapGestureRecognizer *bottomViewGestureRecognizer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIScrollView *parallaxScrollView;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat currentTopHeight;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) UIViewController * topViewController;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) UIViewController<QMBParallaxScrollViewHolder> * bottomViewController;

@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) CGFloat topHeight;

@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) CGFloat initialMaxHeightBorder;
@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) CGFloat initialMinHeightBorder;

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) QMBParallaxState state;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) QMBParallaxGesture lastGesture;

@end

@implementation QMBParallaxScrollViewController



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)dealloc{
    if ([[_backgroundView gestureRecognizers] containsObject:self.topViewGestureRecognizer]){
        [_backgroundView removeGestureRecognizer:self.topViewGestureRecognizer];
    }

    // Remove Observer
    if ([_foregroundView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]){
        UIScrollView *foregroundScrollView = (UIScrollView *)_foregroundView;
        [foregroundScrollView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize"];
    }

    [self.view removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame"];

}

#pragma mark - QMBParallaxScrollViewController Methods

- (void)setupWithTopViewController:(UIViewController *)topViewController andTopHeight:(CGFloat)height andBottomViewController:(UIViewController *)bottomViewController{

    self.topViewController = topViewController;
    self.bottomViewController = bottomViewController;
    _topHeight = height;
    _startTopHeight = _topHeight;
    _maxHeight = self.view.frame.size.height-50.0f;
    [self setMaxHeightBorder:MAX(1.5f*_topHeight, 300.0f)];
    [self setMinHeightBorder:_maxHeight-20.0f];

    [self addChildViewController:self.topViewController];
    _backgroundView = topViewController.view;
    [_backgroundScrollView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
    [_backgroundView setClipsToBounds:YES];

    [self addChildViewController:self.bottomViewController];
    _foregroundView = bottomViewController.view;

    _foregroundScrollView = [UIScrollView new];
    _foregroundScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(topLayoutGuide)]){
        [self.foregroundScrollView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.topLayoutGuide.length, 0, self.bottomLayoutGuide.length, 0)];
    }
    _foregroundScrollView.delegate = self;
    [_foregroundScrollView setAlwaysBounceVertical:YES];
    _foregroundScrollView.frame = self.view.frame;
    _foregroundScrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [_foregroundScrollView addSubview:_foregroundView];

    [self.view addSubview:_foregroundScrollView];
    [self.bottomViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    [self.view addSubview:_backgroundView];
    [self.topViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    [self addGestureReconizer];

    [self updateForegroundFrame];
    [self updateContentOffset];


    // If forground subview is UIScrollView set KV-Observer for any Content Size Changes
    if ([_foregroundView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]){
        UIScrollView *foregroundScrollView = (UIScrollView *)_foregroundView;
        [foregroundScrollView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:0 context:NULL];
    }

    [self.view addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame" options:0 context:NULL];

}

#pragma mark - Obersver

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                       change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void*)context {
    [self updateForegroundFrame];
    [self updateContentOffset];
}

#pragma mark - Gestures

-(void) addGestureReconizer{
    self.topViewGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    [self.topViewGestureRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [self.topViewGestureRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [self.topViewController.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    [self enableTapGestureTopView:YES];
}

- (void)enableTapGestureTopView:(BOOL)enable{
    if (enable) {
        [_backgroundView addGestureRecognizer:self.topViewGestureRecognizer];
    }else {
        [_backgroundView removeGestureRecognizer:self.topViewGestureRecognizer];
    }
}

- (void) handleTap:(id)sender {

    self.lastGesture = QMBParallaxGestureTopViewTap;
    NSLog(@"hi");
    [self showFullTopView: self.state != QMBParallaxStateFullSize];

}

#pragma mark - NSObject Overrides

- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation {
    if ([self.scrollViewDelegate respondsToSelector:[anInvocation selector]]) {
        [anInvocation invokeWithTarget:self.scrollViewDelegate];
    } else {
        [super forwardInvocation:anInvocation];
    }
}

- (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    return ([super respondsToSelector:aSelector] ||
            [self.scrollViewDelegate respondsToSelector:aSelector]);
}



#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate Protocol Methods

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    [self updateContentOffset];
    if ([self.scrollViewDelegate respondsToSelector:_cmd]) {
        [self.scrollViewDelegate scrollViewDidScroll:scrollView];
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate{
    if (!_isAnimating && self.foregroundScrollView.contentOffset.y-_startTopHeight > -_maxHeightBorder && self.state == QMBParallaxStateFullSize){
        [self.foregroundScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];
    }
}


#pragma mark - Public Interface

- (UIScrollView *)parallaxScrollView {
    return self.foregroundScrollView;
}

- (void)setBackgroundHeight:(CGFloat)backgroundHeight {
    _topHeight = backgroundHeight;

    [self updateForegroundFrame];
    [self updateContentOffset];
}


#pragma mark - Internal Methods



- (CGRect)frameForObject:(id)frameObject {
    return frameObject == [NSNull null] ? CGRectNull : [frameObject CGRectValue];
}

#pragma mark Parallax Effect


- (void)updateForegroundFrame {



    if ([_foregroundView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]){
        _foregroundView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, _topHeight, self.view.frame.size.width, MAX(((UIScrollView *)_foregroundView).contentSize.height,_foregroundView.frame.size.height));
        CGSize size = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width,MAX(((UIScrollView *)_foregroundView).contentSize.height,_foregroundView.frame.size.height) + _topHeight);

        self.foregroundScrollView.contentSize = size;
    }else {
        self.foregroundView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f,
                                               _topHeight,
                                               self.foregroundView.frame.size.width,
                                               self.foregroundView.frame.size.height);
        self.foregroundScrollView.contentSize =
        CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width,
                   self.foregroundView.frame.size.height + _topHeight);
    }

}

- (void)updateContentOffset {

    if (2*self.foregroundScrollView.contentOffset.y>_foregroundView.frame.origin.y){
        [self.foregroundScrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:YES];
    }else {
        [self.foregroundScrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
    }

    // Determine if user scrolls up or down
    if (self.foregroundScrollView.contentOffset.y > _lastOffsetY){
        self.lastGesture = QMBParallaxGestureScrollsUp;
    }else {
        self.lastGesture = QMBParallaxGestureScrollsDown;
    }
    _lastOffsetY = self.foregroundScrollView.contentOffset.y;

    self.backgroundView.frame =
    CGRectMake(0.0f,0.0f,self.view.frame.size.width,_topHeight+(-1)*self.foregroundScrollView.contentOffset.y);

    [self.backgroundView layoutIfNeeded];


    if (_isAnimating){
        return;
    }

    if (!_isAnimating && self.lastGesture == QMBParallaxGestureScrollsDown && self.foregroundScrollView.contentOffset.y-_startTopHeight < -_maxHeightBorder && self.state != QMBParallaxStateFullSize){
      // [self showFullTopView:YES];

        return;
    }

    if (!_isAnimating && self.lastGesture == QMBParallaxGestureScrollsUp && -_foregroundView.frame.origin.y + self.foregroundScrollView.contentOffset.y > -_minHeightBorder && self.state == QMBParallaxStateFullSize){
     //  [self showFullTopView:NO];
        return;
    }


}







- (void)tableViewControllerDidScroll:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    if (viewController != self._viewcontroller) {
        return;
    }

    UIViewController * tableView = self._viewcontroller;
    UIView * parallaxView = self.topViewController.view;

    float y = tableView.view.frame.origin.y + self.topViewControllerStandartHeight;

    CGRect currentParallaxFrame = parallaxView.frame;

    if (y > 0) {

        CGFloat newHeight = self.topViewControllerStandartHeight - y;

        [parallaxView setHidden:(newHeight <= 0)];

        if (!parallaxView.hidden) {

            [self willChangeHeightOfTopViewControllerFromHeight:parallaxView.frame.size.height toHeight:newHeight];

            parallaxView.frame = CGRectMake(currentParallaxFrame.origin.x, currentParallaxFrame.origin.y, currentParallaxFrame.size.width, newHeight);

        }

        //uncomment if you want to support section headers - doesnt work 100%
        //        if (y >= self.topViewControllerStandartHeight) {
        //
        //            tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
        //
        //        } else {
        //
        //            tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.topViewControllerStandartHeight - y, 0, 0, 0);
        //
        //        }

    } else {

        [parallaxView setHidden:NO];

        CGFloat newHeight = self.topViewControllerStandartHeight - y;

        [self willChangeHeightOfTopViewControllerFromHeight:parallaxView.frame.size.height toHeight:newHeight];

        parallaxView.frame = CGRectMake(currentParallaxFrame.origin.x, currentParallaxFrame.origin.y, currentParallaxFrame.size.width, newHeight);

        //uncomment if you want to support section headers - doesnt work 100%
        //        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.topViewControllerStandartHeight, 0, 0, 0);

    }

    //[tableView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:parallaxView.hidden];

}



- (void)willChangeHeightOfTopViewControllerFromHeight:(CGFloat)oldHeight toHeight:(CGFloat)newHeight {

   MapViewController  * topViewController = (MapViewController *)self.topViewController;



   // [topViewController willchan]
    [topViewController willChangeHeightFromHeight:oldHeight toHeight:newHeight];

    float r = (self.topViewControllerStandartHeight * 1.5f) / newHeight;
   [self.bottomViewController.view setAlpha:r*r*r*r*r*r];

}










- (void) showFullTopView:(BOOL)show {

    _isAnimating = YES;
    [self.foregroundScrollView setScrollEnabled:NO];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut|UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState|UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews
                     animations:^{

                         [self changeTopHeight:show ?  _maxHeight : _startTopHeight];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){

                         _isAnimating = NO;
                         [self.foregroundScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];

                         if (self.state == QMBParallaxStateFullSize){
                             self.state = QMBParallaxStateVisible;
                             self.maxHeightBorder = self.initialMaxHeightBorder;
                         } else {
                             self.state = QMBParallaxStateFullSize;
                             self.minHeightBorder = self.initialMinHeightBorder;
                         }

                         if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(parallaxScrollViewController:didChangeState:)]){
                             [self.delegate parallaxScrollViewController:self didChangeState:self.state];
                         }
                     }];
}


- (void) changeTopHeight:(CGFloat) height{

    _topHeight = height;

    [self updateContentOffset];
    [self updateForegroundFrame];

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(parallaxScrollViewController:didChangeTopHeight:)]){
        [self.delegate parallaxScrollViewController:self didChangeTopHeight:height];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Borders

- (void)setMaxHeightBorder:(CGFloat)maxHeightBorder{
    _maxHeightBorder = MAX(_topHeight,maxHeightBorder);
    self.initialMaxHeightBorder = maxHeightBorder;
}

- (void)setMinHeightBorder:(CGFloat)minHeightBorder{
    _minHeightBorder = MIN(_maxHeight,minHeightBorder);
    self.initialMinHeightBorder = minHeightBorder;
}

@end
```

here some links that i find it over the internet but they didn't help me to solve my problem [No visible @interface for ____ declares the selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34916432/no-visible-interface-for-declares-the-selector)    [no visible @interface for Book declares the selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813954/no-visible-interface-for-book-declares-the-selector)     [No visible @interface for ____ declares the selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34916432/no-visible-interface-for-declares-the-selector)      [no visible @interface for declares the selector errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20725801/no-visible-interface-for-declares-the-selector-errors)      [No visible @interface for 'xxx' declares the selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24323420/no-visible-interface-for-xxx-declares-the-selector)

here is the message by the compiler :

[image]

Comment: In the first class parallaxcontroller tablevie ...

Comment: i updated my answer take a look @PhillipMills

Comment: as i told in my question i combined 2 library please reread my question i just get the method didviewscroll from another library mentioned in my question

Comment: the first library is https://github.com/quemb/QMBParallaxScrollViewController the second library is https://github.com/peterpaulis/M6ParallaxController

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113216/discussion-between-zakaria-darwish-and-phillip-mills).

Comment: is defined in SampleScrollViewController.h

Comment: yes and i cant deffine the method outside the class

Comment: How to solve this problem